# Haven package adding labels to stata data

Tags: r, r-haven

I have a `Stata` data-set with `0,1` I am reading into `R` using

```
aa <- haven::read_dta("trial_data.dta")
table(aa$malpos)
```

[Link to data](https://github.com/Keniajin/share_data_rcourse/blob/master/trial_data.dta?raw=true)

When its loaded in `R` the variable is comes in with `1,2` categories instead of `0,1`. Is there a way I can avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(haven)

aa %>%
  as_factor()
```